# When using Razor Pages, How can I use RedirectToPage to transfer the contents of an IFormFile?

Tags: asp.net-core

Here's the scenario, I have a 'Index' Razor Page that asks the user for an IFormFile.  The user clicks, and selects a file to upload.

In the OnPostAsync method, I read this large text file (200K+) and want to send the results to the next Razor Page for processing.

```
return RedirectToPage("ConsolidationReport", new {fileContents});
```

But that just gives us a size limit error

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway An internal response header size limit
>   was exceeded

Trying to redirect the IFormFile doesn't work either.

```
return RedirectToPage("ConsolidationReport", new { report = Input.InquiriesReport });
```

There's no error, but the receiving OnGet has null.

And if I process the data and generate the output before redirecting, I get

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

So, what's the correct approach for this?  I'm looking for best practice guidance.

Should I read the file, and create a new IFormFile to send to my target page?  Should I raise the limit of all my requests?
Store in temporary storage?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why at all post to a page which is not the one set up to process the data in the first place? ... simply a waist of resources to do a redirect. Instead post to the proper page straight from the form. Also, you might want to clarify some more what you are trying to do here, as it sounds nuts what you do (unless I missed something here).

Comment: You know LGSon, sometimes you're so deep in a forest, you can't see the trees.  I am fairly new to this Razor Page stuff, and was only considering putting the Post commands on the page asking the question.  Hadn't even considered putting the post on the target page.

Comment: Great, then you weren't doing something nuts, just lost...in the forest :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LGSon for showing me the trees!

ConsolidationModel.cs

```
public class ConsolidationModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile InquiriesReport { get; set; }
}
```

The page that asks for the report parameters becomes very simple.

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class PaymentReportPageModel : ReportPageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public ConsolidationModel Input { get; set; }
}
```

The trick here is to use the target page by specifying asp-page="Report"
Index.cshtml

```
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            ** get start/end dates **

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="Input.ReportFile" class="control-label"></label>:
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input asp-for="Input.ReportFile" type="file" class="form-control" style="height: auto"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

        <button asp-page="Report" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Execute
        </button>
    </form>
```

And use the second BindProperty to receive the data!
Report.cshtml.cs

```
public class ConsolidationPageModel : ReportPageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public ConsolidationModel Input { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
       // Use the data properly.
    }
```